# Написать функцию которая принимает два аргумента

Tags: javascript

Написать функцию которая принимает два аргумента (две одинаковые массивы). Функция возвращает true если все элементы похожи и false если не похожи

я написал это но не работает, плюс если не сложно можете обьяснить?

```js
let x = [1, 3, 5, 8]
let y = [1, 3, 5, 8, 4]

function equal(x, y) {
  if (x == y) {
    console.log(true)
    return true;
  } else if (x !== y) {
    console.log(false)
    return false;
  }
}

equal()
```

Comment: `equal(x, y);` *(1 символ нужен...)*

Comment: @Igor нужна функция которая принимает два аргумента а не один, или я что то не понимаю?

Comment: у вас два аргумента и есть, только проверка не сработает, массивы по ссылке сравниваются

Comment: @ThisMan а как сравнить по содержанию тогда?

Comment: Пройтись по каждому элементу и в начале длинну проверять, чтобы лишнюю првоерку не делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любые объекты в JS (в том числе массивы) при сравнении не будут равны, даже если у них одно содержимое. Поэтому нужно проверять поэлементно.

Вот вариант решения для простых случаев.

```js
let a = [1, 3, 5, 8];
let b = [1, 3, 5, 8];
let c = [1, 3, 5, 7];
let d = [1, 3, 5, 8, 4];

function equal(x, y) {
  return x.length === y.length &&
         x.every((element, index) => y[index] === element);
}

console.log(equal(a, b));
console.log(equal(a, c));
console.log(equal(a, d));
```

Однако он не будет работать, если:

1. Нужно сравнивать рекурсивно (например, элементами массивов могуть быть другие массивы).
2. Требуется нестрогое сравнение (например, элементы `1` и `'1'` должны считаться равными).

По условиям задачи не совсем понятно, требуется ли учёт этих особенностей. Если да, уточните.

Comment: и так сойдет)  благодарю